# Replicar Binários com Java

Tags: java, oracle11g

Estou tentando replicar um campo binário que representa uma imagem no Oracle. Saberiam me dizer a melhor maneira de pegar esses dados e inserir novamente? O campo no Oracle é LONG RAW. Que tipo de dado usar no Java? Já tentei byte e não consegui. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

[Data Type and Java-to-Java Type Mappings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm)

```
 SQL and PL/SQL Data Type    Oracle Mapping            JDBC Mapping

 RAW, LONG RAW               oracle.sql.RAW             byte[]
```

Tente mapeá-lo para `byte[]`.

Se você conseguir `java.sql.SQLException`: `Stream has already been closed`, tente definir `useFetchSizeWithLongColumn = true` as propriedades de conexão para o `OJDBC driver`.

[Veja a OracleDriver API](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)

Comment: ok, legal então coloca a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo uma solução:

```
    String query = "SELECT NOME, IMAGEM FROM LR_TABLE WHERE ID = 1";
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    try {                   
        String nome = null;         
        while (rs.next()) {
            nome = rs.getString("nome");                    
            byte longRaw[] = rs.getBytes("imagem");             
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(longRaw);

            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO LR_TABLE (ID, NOME, IMAGEM) VALUES (21, ?, ?)");              
            ps.setString(1, nome);
            ps.setBinaryStream(2, stream);          
            ps.execute();
            ps.close();
        }
```